# add fix header xy scroll to table using mCustomScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have a table and data is generated using ajax call...I want `thead` should be sticky on y-axis but x-axis scroll on y-axis and both  scroll on x-axis.

```
$('.graphData table tbody, .graphData table thead').empty();

var listTitle = $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>Month</td><td>orders</td><td>products</td><td>sub total</td><td>shipping</td><td>coupon</td><td>bundle</td><td>credit</td><td>tax</td><td>total sale</td><td>total cost</td><td>total profit</td><td>profit [%]</td>');


$('.graphData table thead').append(listTitle);


$.each(json.graph_data, function(index){


  var list = $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+json.graph_data[index][0]+'</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][1]+'</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][2]+'</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][3]+' AED</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][4]+' AED</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][5]+' AED</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][6]+' AED</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][7]+' AED</td><td>'+json.graph_data[index][8]+' AED</td><td class="sale">'+json.graph_data[index][9]+' AED</td><td class="cost">'+json.graph_data[index][10]+' AED</td><td class="profit">'+json.graph_data[index][11]+' AED</td><td class="profit">'+json.graph_data[index][12]+' %</td>');


  $('.graphData table tbody').append(list);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="graphData" data-mcs-axis="yx" style="width:86.5% !important;">

            <div class="graphDataTitle">
                <table class="thead">
                    <thead></thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="graphDataInner">
                <table>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
</div>
```

using this code ...table and data generated successfully but `thead` is not sticky.there is too much data in `tbody` so i want to add scroll on tbody on x and y axis but on x-axis only to `thead` along with `tbody` .

Thanks for any suggestion and help...

Comment: What exacly is your problem? What is wrong in this fiddle?

Comment: that fiddle table is hard coded but my table is generated through ajax... i am confused how to fix my problem

Comment: Then please create a snippet where you will reproduce your problem. Because for now it seems fine.

Comment: i just want to make head of table to stay fix at y axis but scroll on x-axis along with tbody

Comment: If you don't mind not supporting it on old browsers have you considered `position: sticky`?

Comment: @DominicTobias I tried but it didnot work...

Comment: i am using this plugin also https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues ... which apply xy scroll on complete div on table container ...can you tell me how to apply x scroll on thead and xy scroll on tbody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are using mCustomeScroll plugin... you need to change following...

**HTML**

```
<div class="graphData" data-mcs-axis="x">
    <table class="fixed_headers">
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody >

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript for mCustomScroll**

```
$(window).load(function(){

 $("table.fixed_headers tbody").mCustomScrollbar({
  mouseWheel:{ preventDefault: true },
  autoExpandScrollbar:true
 });

 $(".graphData").mCustomScrollbar({
  scrollbarPosition:"outside"
 });

});
```

**Change seletors in ajax request**

```
$('table.fixed_headers thead').append(listTitle);
$('table.fixed_headers tbody .mCSB_container').append(list);
```

[Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/dragospaulpop/pen/asBcI)

!! THATS IT !!

Comment: should i mention `data-mcs-axis='yx'` to tbody ?

Comment: nope... bcz of `mCSB_container` ...by default scroll will apply to both axis

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is position sticky, though it's not supported on all browsers. Table layouts are different to normal ones and for example min-height and scoll doesn't work on them unless you start doing nasty hacks like `display: block` on them and then you run into other layout issues.

```css
div {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

/* This is just to demonstrate that the table can horizontally scroll */
table {
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it does, did you try it? https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky - works on th elements as the demo above uses